# Probability measure on the space of $n \times n$ symmetric matrices with non negative integer coefficients

Tags: probability, matrices, probability-theory

I know that there exists a particular measure, called [Haar measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure), defined on random matrices, i.e. $n \times n$ orthogonal complex matrices. 
My question is the following: can we define a probability measure on the space of $n \times n$ symmetric matrices with non negative integer coefficients? If yes, can you suggest me some case?

Answer (score 0):

The key feature of Haar measure is that it's invariant under (left) multiplication. The group of symmetric invertible matrices is noncompact, so the Haar measure is not finite - in particular it can't be a probability measure.